# Cuál es la diferencia entre apt install y apt-get install?

Tags: linux, unix, terminal

Tengo entendido que ambos descargan e instalan paquetes, pero no sé cuando sirve uno y cuando sirve el otro.

Comment: En pocas palabras: apt = las opciones de comando más comunes de apt-get y apt-cache. Si está interesado en aprender más, te recomiendo [diferencias entre apt-get y apt-cache](https://adictec.com/diferencia-comandos-apt-y-apt-get/).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Es una interfaz para el usuario, algo así como el frontend de ciertas herramientas que manejan asuntos relacionados con paquetes. Es decir, hace uso de funcionalidades presentes en programas como:

- `apt-get`, considerado como el back-end de otras herramientas que usan la librería de APT. Algunas de sus funciones más comunes son descargar, instalar, y eliminar paquetes para sistemas Debian.
- `apt-cache`, muestra información útil del paquete de metadatos.
- `dpkg-query`, herramienta que sirve para mostrar información sobre los paquetes listados en la base de datos de dpkg.

`apt` es una interfaz que hace uso de las funcionalidades más comunes de estos programas, además de realizar otras acciones como editar la lista de fuentes de paquetes (el `sources.list`).

Pongamos un ejemplo. `apt-get` tiene una opción de *download*, que sirve para descargar un paquete de instalación en el directorio actual. Con `apt` puedes hacer exactamente lo mismo:

```
$ sudo apt-get download zsh
$ sudo apt download zsh  # Es equivalente
```

Otro ejemplo es usando:

```
$ sudo apt-cache search ^zsh
$ sudo apt search ^zsh
```

En el cual ambos comandos traerán información semejante sobre los paquetes que tengan ese patrón. **Semejante, pero no igual**.

Para obtener más información, puedes leer la documentación de cada programa referido.

A veces es mejor utilizar otra herramienta para instalar que el mero uso del `apt-get`, por ejemplo `synaptic`o `aptitude`. **No** siempre es la mejor opción utilizar sólo `apt-get` para instalar.

Un ejemplo de esto sería descargar una versión específica de un, digamos, compilador de *c* o *c++*. Con `synaptic`  o `aptitude`, podrías instalar de manera precisa y rápida la versión deseada, o cambiar de una versión a otra de forma sencilla. También podrías hacerlo con `apt-get`, pero la búsqueda y tecleo lo harían desde tedioso hasta propenso a tener un desorden de versiones.

Como `apt` está enfocado para el usuario, se puede usar para hacer labores rápidas en la consola. Sin embargo, para evitar **problemas de retrocompatiblidad**, es mejor que se usen los programas a los que se refiere `apt` (con sus respectivas opciones habilitadas) que a `apt` mismo en la escritura de scripts.

Que es una paráfrasis de `man apt(8)`

```
SCRIPT USAGE AND DIFFERENCES FROM OTHER APT TOOLS

    The apt(8) commandline is designed as an end-user tool and it may change 
    behavior between versions. While it tries not to break backward 
    compatibility this is not guaranteed either if a change seems beneficial 
    for interactive use.

    All features of apt(8) are available in dedicated APT tools like apt- 
    get(8) and apt-cache(8) well. apt(8) just changes the default value of 
    some options (see apt.conf(5) and specifically the Binary scope). 
    So you should prefer using these commands (potentially with some 
    additional options enabled) in your scripts as they keep backward 
    compatibility as much as possible.
```

### ¿Cuándo usar `apt` o `apt-get`?

Depende, si vas a trabajar en la línea de comandos actividades comunes, requieres una UI amigable para instalar de forma rápida y precisa ciertas versiones de programas, o vas a hacer scripts, o requieres de las funcionalidades propias de programas como apt-get, apt-cache, etc., requieres de retrocompatiblidad (esto es más enfocado al caso de scripts).

Answer (score 2):

Ambos comandos te servirán, lo que ocurre es que el comando `apt` es nuevo, algo así como la nueva versión de `apt-get` este comando (apt) combina varias funciones de `apt-get` y `apt-cache` en un solo comando, esto para mejorar la experiencia del usuario final y éste no tenga que estar buscando comandos adicionales en caso de que las dependecias del programa que se instala no estén disponibles, sin embargo `apt-get` por ser más antiguo, tiene mayor rigidez sobre `apt`.

Por experiencia propia, te recomiendo usar el comando que se creó inicialmente para la instalación de paquetes `apt-get install` ya que ha ido teniendo soporte desde su creación, por lo tanto es más robusto y confiable que `apt`.

Comment: Gracias. Ambos sirven de todas maneras, ¿verdad?

Comment: Exacto, ambos realizan la función de descargar e instalar.

Comment: Perfecto, muchas gracias