# ¿Qué significa la 'y' en el comando :`sudo apt install -y mongodb`

Tags: linux, línea-de-comandos

El comando lo he sacado de un curso que estoy haciendo, el caso es que he buscado en internet sobre el comando install y no veo el parametro 'y'  también he ejecutado install --help y me sale :

```
  -C, --compare           
  -c                      
  -d, --directory         
  -D
  -g, --group=GROUP   
  -m, --mode=MODE     
  -o, --owner=OWNER   
  -p, --preserve-timestamps 
  -s, --strip             elimina las tablas de símbolos
  -S, --suffix=SUFIJO     reemplaza el sufijo de respaldo habitual
  -t, --target-directory=DIRECTORIO  copia todos los argumentos ORIGEN
                                     al DIRECTORIO
  -T, --no-target-directory  trata DESTINO como fichero normal
  -v, --verbose           muestra el nombre de cada directorio conforme se
                          van creando
      --preserve-context  preserve SELinux security context
  -Z                      set SELinux security context of destination
                            file and each created directory to default type
      --context[=CTX]     like -Z, or if CTX is specified then set the
                            SELinux or SMACK security context to CTX
      --help     muestra esta ayuda y finaliza
      --version  informa de la versión y finaliza

´´´
no veo que opcion ' y'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Neoniet dio una respuesta que me parece buena pero incompleta. Quisiera complementarla con una [respuesta que di](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/226389/cu%C3%A1l-es-la-diferencia-entre-apt-install-y-apt-get-install/226530#226530) sobre diferencias entre `apt` y `apt-get` que pudiera expandir un poco la respuesta.

`apt`, como una especie de *frontend* de varias funciones de APT como `apt-get`, tiene la opción de `-y` "heredada" de `apt-get`, la cual la explica @Neoniet. Sin embargo, me gustaría añadir varias cosas, entre ellas que la opción `-y`, o similares, en varios comandos volvieron obsoleta la utilidad principal del comando `yes`, que imprime la letra `y` o la cadena subsiguiente.

Otro tema a añadir es que tú utilizaste la ayuda proporcionada por la opción `--help` sobre el comando `install` que es muy diferente a `apt install`. Ambos son temas diferentes, `install` es un comando creado para copiar archivos a una dirección y ponerle permisos y atributos configurables, en cambio, `apt` es lo que @Neoniet menciona, y mi respuesta en otra pregunta da, pero seguida del parámetro `install`. Es decir, `$ install` es un comando y `$ apt install` es el comando `apt` con el parámetro `install`.

El último tema por añadir es que si quieres ver la descripción, opciones, ejemplos sobre un comando o programa, tienes las opciones de `man comando`, `comando --help` (o como lo defina el programa, ya sea con `-h`, etc) o `info comando`. En ese sentido, `man apt-get` tiene más información que `apt-get --help`, o digamos que, hasta donde yo he visto, la opción `--help` es más práctica o de cuestiones de mero uso, a diferencia de `man` e `info`.

Answer (score 5):

`apt` es una interfaz a varias utilidades del sistema de gestión de paquetes debian. En concreto esta opción viene del comando `apt-get` y es un habitual en muchos comandos unix. Es un sí automático en cualquier hipotética pregunta que pueda hacerte `apt` al instalar.

Si quieres ver más detalles sobre la ayuda tienes que usar `man apt-get`. En concreto sobre ésta opción:

> −y, −−yes, −−assume−yes
>
> Supone una respuesta afirmativa a todas las preguntas, de esta forma
>   apt−get se ejecuta sin necesidad de intervención posterior para tomar
>   decisiones. apt−get terminará sin hacer nada de producirse una
>   situación no deseada, como cambiar un paquete retenido, instalar un
>   paquete sin autenticar o desinstalar un paquete esencial. Opción de
>   configuración: APT::Get::Assume−Yes.